# Misunderstanding of how the Read trait works for TcpStreams

Tags: tcp, rust

My goal is to read some bytes from a TcpStream in order to parse the data in each message and build a struct from it.

```
loop {
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let len = stream.read(&mut buf)?;
    if 0 == len {
        //Disconnected
    }
    println!("read() -> {}", len);
}
```

Like in Python, I thought the `stream.read()` would block until it received some data.
So I've set up a server that calls the loop you see above for each incoming connection. I've then tried to connect to the server with netcat; netcat connects successfully to the server and blocks on the `stream.read()`, which is what I want; but as soon as I send some data, `read()` returns `0`.
I've also tried doing something similar with `stream.read_to_end()` but it only appears to only return when the connection is closed.

How can I read from the TcpStream, message per message, knowing that each message can have a different, unknown, size ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting caught with your pants down by an underlying technicality of `Vec` more than by `std::io::Read`, although they both interact in this particular case.

The definition and documentation of `Read` states:

> If the return value of this method is Ok(n), then it **must be guaranteed that 0 <= n <= buf.len()**. A nonzero n value indicates that the buffer buf has been filled in with n bytes of data from this source. If n is 0, then it can indicate one of two scenarios:

The important part is bolded.

When you define a new `Vec` the way you did, it starts with a capacity of *zero*. This means that the underlying slice (that you will use as a buffer) has a length of zero. As a result, since it must be guaranteed that `0 <= n <= buf.len()` and since `buf.len()` is zero, your `read()` call immediately returns with 0 bytes read.

To "fix" this, you can either assign a default set of elements to your `Vec` (`Vec::new().resize(1024, 0)`), or just use an array from the get-go (`let mut buffer:[u8; 1024] = [0; 1024]`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `stream.read()` still returns Ok(0), even though if created a vector with `Vec::with_capacity(1024)`.
I've printed it's len before and after the read... `0` for both.
The capacity remains `1024`

Comment: @Stargateur yes, I was just giving details

Comment: @EconoMix What is your actual `TcpStream`? As in, are you certain the issue is on the rust side?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld the `TcpStream` is from `TcpListener::incoming()`
I'm sure the issue is on my side, I think there is something I am not seeing or understanding about TcpStream that is different from, for example, python sockets

Comment: @EconoMix I forgot a crucial step, which Stargateur reminded me of. You actually need to use that capacity as well (i.e. `resize()`)...or, once again, use an array from the get-go (I almost never read into `Vec`s).

Comment: Solved it, thanks
I created the vector with `vec![0; 1024]`
I guess it just needed to be initialized